# ASP.NET MVC and HTML "<img" tag pointing to a URL which returns another URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, redirect

There is a legacy web site whose  tags point to a Microsoft .NET Web API endpoint which currently dumps the bytes of an image to HTTP response output.

I want to re-write this Web API and instead of dumping the image on the screen I would like to put the generated image somewhere on Amazon S3 and just return a Cloud Front url which points to that image. In more crude terms I want the new API to return the path of the image rather than its binary data.

My question is that if my API returns an HTTP Redirect , will the image be able to retrieve the image from the new location without redirecting the whole page? What is the best way of replacing the legacy API in such a scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a better approach could be that the ViewModel hold the final URLs.
Then, in your view, you just set the proper URL to the `img` tag.

So, in your controller, you call the API to do the logic of putting the image in S3 and get the URL. Then you put that URL in the viewmodel with the other data required by your view.

This way, you don't need to worry about redirection... and your view is clean of logic.

Answer (score 0):

A redirect result (301 or 302) would work just fine, the image would still load correctly.  I would caution you to use the 301/Permanent redirect in case you have search engine rankings in play.

You could always try this yourself.  In a test project, setup a controller action that returns a redirect result to a physical image.  Then test!

```
public ActionResult ImageUrl(){
     return Redirect("~/Content/Images/image.jpg")
}
```

In your view:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("ImageUrl", "Home")"/>
```

This should return whatever image you pointed to in your `Redirect()`